# How to update cell value at infragistics at method beforecellupdate

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm using an `Infragistics UltraGrid` and I have a table where the first column is a `Double` field, I use a `dll NCalc.Expression` so the user can input a formula and get a double value, of course only if it is a valid formula. The problem is on method `beforeCellUpdate`, I can't change the value to the value generated by the evaluate method from `NCalc.Expression`. I tried to store the new value as a class variable and then update the value at `afterCellUpdate` method but then I get a Data Error - [data error due to formula being not a double but a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3OQ1.png), input not valid

What does this mean? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you post your code? Is the method to generate the value outputting a string?

Answer (score 0):

After all night I use the method berofeExitEditMode, that way I evaluate the input formula, if its not valid cancel the event, if the formula its correct, then change the value for the generated value.
It worked so far.
IF anyone knows a better way it would be much appreciated